# MySQL 5.7 - Query to set the value of a JSON key to a JSON Object

Tags: mysql, json

Using **MySQL 5.7**, how to set the value of a JSON key in a JSON column to a JSON object rather than a string.

I used this query:

```
SELECT json_set(profile, '$.twitter', '{"key1":"val1", "key2":"val2"}')
from account WHERE id=2
```

**Output:**

```
{"twitter": "{\"key1\":\"val1\", \"key2\":\"val2\"}", "facebook": "value", "googleplus": "google_val"}
```

But it seems like it considers it as a string since the output escapes the JSON characters in it. Is it possible to do that without using `JSON_OBJECT()`?

Answer (score 1):

There's a couple of options that I know of:

- Use the `JSON_UNQUOTE` function to unquote the output (ie not cast it to string) as [documented here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json-modification-functions.html#function_json-unquote)
- Possibly use the `->>` operator and select a specific path, documented [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json.html#json-path-syntax)
- Has a lot of implications, but you could disable backslashes as an escape character. I haven't tried this, so I don't even know if that works, but it's mentioned in [the docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_no_backslash_escapes)

On balance, I'd either use the `->>` operator, or handle the conversion on the client side, depending on what you want to do.